# SonarQube analysis reports error "Unable to parse file" for all Python3 source files

Tags: maven, python-3.x, sonarqube

Some background:
I am using a tiny / dummy pom.xml to facilitate SonarQube analysis for Python3 source code.  All Python3 source files are triggering this SonarQube error...

Sample error message (with the entire source code of the file):

```
[ERROR] [23:13:30.135] Unable to parse file: /home/kca/saveme2/git/kevinarpe-rambutan3/rambutan3/RTestUtil.py
[ERROR] [23:13:30.135] Parse error at line 3 column 33:

  -->  def test_eq_and_ne(left, right, *, is_equal: bool):
    4:     assert is_equal == (left == right)
    5:     assert is_equal != (left != right)
    6: 
    7: 
    8: 
    9: EOF
```

The error above seems to complain about Python3 function args trick to force caller to specify arguments by name.

To precisely reproduce, do git clone of this repo (https://github.com/kevinarpe/kevinarpe-rambutan3) and run `./sonarqube.bash` (tiny script to setup env and run `mvn sonar:sonar`).

Perhaps this is a pylint issue or environment issue (on my side).  I am running from a Debian GNU/Linux box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's due to a bug in the plugin's parser: for the parameter list of a function declaration, it only recognizes Python 2.x syntaxes.

I created the following ticket to fix it in the next version: http://jira.sonarsource.com/browse/SONARPY-122

Comment: Wow... I am honoured with a "major" bug on SonarQube JIRA.  ^..^  Huzah!

Comment: How does one report similar bugs? There is type-hinting issue for python3 syntax as well

Comment: @JackLeo Bugs should be reported to the [sonarqube google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/sonarqube).